# Why isn't Play excluding my dependency?

Tags: dependencies, playframework

My deps file:

```
- org.hibernate -> hibernate-core 3.6.8.Final:
    force: true
    exclude:
        - ant -> ant 1.6.5

- org.apache.ant -> ant 1.8.2
```

(Note that the ant I'm trying to exclude is from the `ant` group, while the ant I'm including is from `org.apache.ant` - sadly, the `ant` group does not yet contain ant 1.8.2).

When I run play deps , I find that the exclude is not taking effect, and I end up with both versions of ant in my lib folder.

The output from `play deps --sync --debug` is [here](https://gist.github.com/1497529). Any advice on how to resolve this?
Here is the shorter output without the `--debug`:

```
~ Resolving dependencies using C:\work\CS\portal\src\conf\dependencies.yml,
~
~   org.hibernate->hibernate-core 3.6.8.Final (from mavenCentral)
~   javax.validation->validation-api 1.0.0.GA (from mavenCentral)
~   ant->ant 1.6.5 (from mavenCentral)
~   javassist->javassist 3.12.0.GA (from mavenCentral)
~   cglib->cglib 2.2 (from mavenCentral)
~   asm->asm 3.1 (from mavenCentral)
~   org.apache.ant->ant 1.8.2 (from mavenCentral)
~   org.apache.ant->ant-launcher 1.8.2 (from mavenCentral)
~
~ Some dependencies have been evicted,
~
~   hibernate-core 3.6.1.Final is overriden by hibernate-core 3.6.8.Final
~   hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.1.Final is overriden by hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.0.Final
~   commons-collections 3.1 is overriden by commons-collections 3.2.1
~
~ Installing resolved dependencies,
~
~   lib/hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar
~   lib/ant-1.8.2.jar
~   lib/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
~   lib/ant-1.6.5.jar
~   lib/javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
~   lib/cglib-2.2.jar
~   lib/asm-3.1.jar
~   lib/ant-launcher-1.8.2.jar
~
~ *****************************************************************************
~ WARNING: These dependencies are missing, your application may not work properly (use --verbose for details),
~
~   org.jboss.javaee->jboss-jacc-api_JDK4 1.1.0
~ *****************************************************************************
~
~ Some dependencies are still missing.
~
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.2.x-c40cf37, http://www.playframework.org
~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess force:true is causing both files to be copied. Seems like [DependencyManager#install](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/deps/DependenciesManager.java#L235) isn't considering the excluded deps.

This seems to do what you want:

```
 require:                                                                                                                                                                                       
    - org.hibernate -> hibernate-core 3.6.8.Final:                                                                                                                                             
        exclude:                                                                                                                                                                               
          - ant -> ant *                                                                                                                                                                       
    - play:                                                                                                                                                                                    
        exclude:                                                                                                                                                                               
          - org.hibernate -> hibernate-core                                                                                                                                                    
    - org.apache.ant -> ant 1.8.2
```